# How to batch export using r.out.gdal command in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, r, export

I created a list of files (`NPPFILES`) using `g.mlist` command in GRASS 7.
Now I would like to export these files as .tiff files.
I tried this command in GRASS prompt

```
for files in $NPPFILES; do
r.out.gdal input="$NPPFILES" output="$NPPFILES.tiff" format=GTiff ; done
```

This is not working for me. I'm running it in the directory where output files need to be stored, still no result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate through the files, so your loop should be as follows:

```
for file in $NPPFILES
do
    r.out.gdal input=$file output=$file.tif format=GTiff 
done
```

You should add the semi-colons if you write the loop on one line.