# export several rasters from grass

Tags: raster, grass-gis, export

I'd like to export 127 raster files from grass to .tif in one operation. I already stumbled over this post [How to batch export using r.out.gdal command in GRASS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112704/how-to-batch-export-using-r-out-gdal-command-in-grass) but it doesn't work (I don't even know exactly where to enter this -python console or command shell?).

I'm not too familiar with programming, so I hope there's a simple solution.

Comment: The answer in the post that you mentioned definitely works. It is intended to be run in a bash shell. Yu can do a similar loop in python if you prefer. Can you show what you did that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I enter it in the command console as follows: 
for file in $NPPFILES; do r.out.gdal input=$file output=$file.tif format=GTiff ; done
which results the following:
"file" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet
werden. ("file" cannot be processed in this place, syntax error)

Perhaps I should mention I'm using Windows7 w/o admin rights.

Comment: The previous post refers to a bash shell. You will have to write the equivalent commands for windows cmd. Maybe this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop will give you some ideas